# How can I select a word from a line?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

Basically I'm really stuck, I want to select a simple word(which is a number) from a sentence from a specified line. Here's the code:

```
        Dim index As Integer = Me.RichTextBox1.Find("<h3>Current Guide Price <span title='")
        If index <> -1 Then
        Dim lineindex As Integer = Me.RichTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(index)
        Dim first As Integer = Me.RichTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineindex)
        Dim last As Integer = Me.RichTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineindex + 1)
        If last = -1 Then last = Me.RichTextBox1.TextLength
        Me.RichTextBox1.Select(first, last - first)
        Me.RichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.DeepPink
        Dim txxt As String
        txxt = Me.RichTextBox1.SelectedText
        Label1.Text = txxt
```

[image]

Like I've shown in the picture, I want the 513.703 in the label1 instead of the whole line "Current Guide Price   513.7k" If you could help me I would grantly appreciate it!

Comment: Is it possible that string exists more than once?

Comment: The txxt, yeah it's basically an incomplete code, I couldn't find the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to use this regex on the selected text:

```
'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)'
```

**Explanation:**

```
'   : Looks for single quote character
\d+ : Digit [0-9] one or more time
\.  : dot character
()  : make a group
?:  : mark group as non-capturing
?   : makes the group optional
```

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/U8QJ4fz5GY)

**Sample code:** (untested code to give you an idea)

```
Dim m as System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Me.RichTextBox1.SelectedText, "'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)'", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None)
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(m.Tostring())
```

Comment: Wow! Never heard about these Regex ruby codes. I find them really logical same for the code you gave me, but the "Match" and "Regex" part doesn't look defined. For Diagnostic it seems like it's not a part of system, I'll still look through.

Comment: @J-sGrenier Add `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` at the top of your code file to avoid the problems with Match and RegexOptions. The second statement should be 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(m.Tostring())' ("s" at the end of Diagnostics).

Comment: Agree with @Blackwood. You can either specify the namespace at the top of your code or use it the way i used. try my edited answer.

Comment: @NeverHopeless , What does the "m" replace in that case?

Comment: @J-sGrenier, I am expecting that `Me.RichTextBox1.SelectedText` containing text `<h3>Current Guide Price <span title='513.703'>  513.7k`. In my sample code `m.ToString()` will extract `513.703` from selected text which is your required result.